# WPF datagrid height is infinite

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have two datagrids (data grid 1 and 2) which are being bound from a separate User Control:

```
      <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >               
        <local:DATAGRID1    x:Name="DATAGRID1" /></Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">   
        <local:DATAGRID2   x:Name="DATAGRID2" /> </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="AddURLContainer" Grid.Column="1" >
            <StackPanel>
            <local:test1 x:Name="NewQueryControl"/>
            <local:test2 x:Name="AddURLControl" />
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

But for some reason the data grids stretch longer than the window and don't constrain within the windows height. I've attempted to put the Datagrids in a scroll viewer but the scroll bar also goes out of the window and doesn't constrain. I can't figure out why its doing this. 
The opening tags of the actual data grids are (and they are wrapped in a User control not a Stackpannel):

```
<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
           IsReadOnly="True" 
           SelectionMode="Single" 
           >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed to be fixed if I change the above main grids row properties from:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

To:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Strange fix but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why are using * width and heigt?

Use Auto:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Auto set the size to it's allocated content.

Comment: column width is set to * because the stuff in "AddURLContainer" is toggled as a collapsed panel. Even if I have them all as auto it still doesn't constrain the data grids within the window, the data grids still overflow

Comment: Overflows on what? on  "AddURLContainer"?

Comment: Overflows outside the main window - it doesn't constrain. You actually gave me an idea though and I checked the main parent containers and changing the height from 'auto' to '*' fixed it, strangely enough... As you said auto would have been more appropriate than * but * worked